# How to get number of open files in Redhat

Tags: redhat

My application gives too many open Files exception.so I need to take the open file count in Redhat. lsof command gives 'command not found'.

Comment: I think you should be able to use the `ls` command for this. Use `ps aux | grep <yourapp>` to find the `pid` for your processes, then run `lsof -p <pid>` and `lsof -a -p <pid>`. You could also try `cd /proc/<pid>/fd` and `ls -l | less`. The count files execute `ls -l | wc -l`

Comment: I also think you must execute the `lsof` command as root, have you tried running `su lsof ...`?

Comment: @Cyclone su lsof also not working.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the command? Try `where lsof`, `whereis lsof` or `locate lsof`, to use `locate` you might wan't to update the database calling `updatedb` before running `locate`

Comment: lsof file is missing inside /usr/sbin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/lsof-command-not-found-39461/):

The lsof command is available only to root. Anyway, if you want to run it as a normal user, you can specify its full path:

```
$ /usr/sbin/lsof /path/to/some/file
```

Alternatively as [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/s1-managing-locating.html) indicates, you can display information about open files, by typing the `files` command at the interactive prompt. You can use files pid to display files opened by the selected process.